# How to identify a selected graphic element(s) in python

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, layouts, graphics

I have a situation where I am inserting items from Excel into maps a lot.  When I insert the items it always makes them a fixed width and then adjusts height to maintain aspect ratio.

What I would like to do is paste the object, then click my tool.  THis would prompt me for a number of units the item should be, and the tool would then resize it appropriately.

I am able to get to a list of graphic elements ( narrowed down to photo elements even) using

```
arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT")
```

But, I'm not sure how to identify which one/ones are selected in order to start manipulating it/them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This capability is not exposed in arcpy -- the help topic [Guidelines for arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006s000000) discusses some of these limitations. The expected workflow is that you must uniquely name all elements you want to manipulate, not arbitrary elements that the user selects interactively. For that you would need to use ArcObjects.